# Changing input value of a form

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to change the value of input element or "textarea" using Puppeteer and NodeJS
I tried this code

```
const pupp = require('puppeteer')


async function scrape() {
    const url = "https://google.com"
    const browser = await pupp.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: 'load',
        timeout: 0
    });
    
    const input = await page.$eval('body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > input' , e1 => e1.value = 'hello');

    const  text = await page.$eval('body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > input' , e1 => e1.innerText);
    
    console.log(text)
    
}
```

I am trying to change the input of Google search input
and nothing happened
any ideas to help ??!

Comment: Try `e1 => e1.value` instead of innerText

Comment: okay .. thank u .. it worked
what if i want to click a button (sign in)
and i want to know which page will this button go to ??

Comment: That is good that you've already found your answer in the first comment. I suggest rather check if your new topic (clicking the button + identifying the first result) is already answered on SO or raise a new question purely dedicated to that topic. It will make your question and its answers searchable for others later.